# Can a OCR confuse letter case?

Tags: ocr, characters

Can a OCR sometimes confuse between letter case?
For example 't' interpreted as 'T' or 'r' as 'R' at some point?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OCR works by analysing the shape of the letters. It's more likely to confuse the letter "l" and the numeral "1" for example as they are very similar in shape. Lower case "t" and upper case "T" are more different, so as long the letters are clear enough I wouldn't have thought so.

Have you got an example where it's done this?

Comment: Yes, for example: the word 'ocr' appear as 'oCR' on very rare occasion.

Comment: @user754221 - given that "ocr" should really be written "OCR" there might be some rules in the software you use that does some autoconversion in cases like this, but it's hard to see how it would only partially capitalise the letters.

Comment: I re-checked, it looks like there could have been a software bug.